# OpenCV - find a portion of a contour of a certain shape?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, contour

At first this seemed like an easy one, but at the moment I'm stumped.  Given a fairly elaborate and irregular contour such as this:

[image]

How can the portion of the contour that is shaped like 3/4 of a square be identified?

[image]

Any ideas ??

Comment: Is the shape going to change on other data samples? Will the 3/4 of a rectangle that you're trying to find have a different size or orientation? Please remember to paint the whole picture if you expect reasonable answers.

Comment: you can evaluate the changes in direction or fit lines. in both cases you should evaluate segments that are almost as long as the expected rectangle sides.